# How to search within current folder and sub folder (Spacemacs)

Tags: spacemacs

When I do space + s + P, I can search within the project which is cool. But I would like to search in current foler and subfolder. how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### When I'm looking for file names:

`M-x find-name-dired`

I have it bound to `SPC f d`

`(global-set-key (kbd "M-m f d") 'find-name-dired)`

### When I'm looking for text search (grep)

- `M-x rgrep`
- `SPC f g`